# cant run the program but not showing any error

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, python-3.x, coding-style

I cant run the program.But there is no error showing that the code is wrong I wanted to make a quiz program and how to combine this code with my other code do we need to use TopLevel? .This is my code:

```
import Tkinter
MathsEasyLevel1 = Tkinter.Tk()
MathsEasyLevel1.geometry("320x260")
MathsEasyLevel1.title("Mathematics Easy")
total = 0

getanswer = Tkinter.IntVar()
getanswer2 = Tkinter.StringVar()

def userinput():
    Answer1 = getanswer.get()
    if Answer1 == 8 :
        total = total + 1
        MathsEasyLevel1.withdraw()
        MathsEasyLevel2.deiconify()

    else :
        total = total
        MathsEasyLevel1.withdraw()
        MathsEasyLevel2.deiconify()
    return

def userinput2():
    Answer2 = getanswer2.get()
    if Answer2 == B :
        total = total + 1
        MathsEasyLevel2.withdraw()
        ResultBox.deiconify()

    else :
        total = total
        MathsEasyLevel2.withdraw()
        ResultBox.deiconify()
    return

LabelName1 = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel1, text="Question 1", font=("Impact",20))
LabelName1.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="new")

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel1, text="State the number of edges in a cube")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (MathsEasyLevel1, textvariable= getanswer)
TxtBoxName.grid(row=2,column=0)
TxtBoxName.pack()

MathsEasyLevel2 = Tkinter.Tk()
MathsEasyLevel2.geometry("320x260")
MathsEasyLevel2.title("Mathematics Easy")

BtnName = Tkinter.Button (MathsEasyLevel1, text="Next", command=userinput).pack()


LabelName3 = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel2, text="Question 2", font=("Impact",20))
LabelName3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="new")

LabelName3 = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel2, text="What is the place value of the digit 4 in 76421?")
LabelName3.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName3.pack()

LabelName4 = Tkinter.Label (MathsEasyLevel2, text="A.Thousands B.Hundreds C.Ones D.Tens")
LabelName4.grid(row=2,column=0)
LabelName4.pack()

TxtBoxName2 = Tkinter.Entry (MathsEasyLevel2, textvariable= getanswer2)
TxtBoxName2.grid(row=3,column=0)
TxtBoxName2.pack()

BtnName2 = Tkinter.Button (MathsEasyLevel2, text="Next", command=userinput2).pack()
MathsEasyLevel2.withdraw()

ResultBox = Tkinter.Tk()
ResultBox.geometry("320x260")
ResultBox.title("Results")

LabelName5 = Tkinter.Label (ResultBox, text="Total correct answers :"+ `total` , font=("Impact",20))
LabelName5.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="new")

LabelName5 = Tkinter.Label (ResultBox, text="Marks : "+`(total/2*100)`, font=("Impact",20))
LabelName5.grid(row=2,column=0)
ResultBox.withdraw()

def userinput3():
    ResultBox.withdraw()
    MenuBox.deiconify()
    return

MathsEasyLevel1.mainloop()
```

Comment: @WoLy this my other code to combine with the level code but i wanted to test this first but it didnt run

Comment: @adrianus can you check my problem my my mark() function not work properly in resultbox

Answer (score 0):

Please give more information on how you are trying to run this and what is the "output" you're getting. Are you getting errors? Is it running properly? Also, I would recommend using a main class instead of trying to run code in the middle of your file.

@edit And next time please try to make the title more representative (language, etc)

Comment: my output is the result box deiconify showing the total mark.Before the resultbox deiconify there will button in matheasylevel2 show to calculate the marks

Comment: i already found the solution but my result mark not work properly

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution but the mark for the resultbox doesnt work.It doesnt calculate the total.These is my new code:

```
import Tkinter 
import tkMessageBox

#easybox1
EasyBox1 = Tkinter.Tk()
EasyBox1.geometry("250x200")
EasyBox1.title("Quesion 1")

Tkinter.Label (EasyBox1, text="answer:").pack()

answr1 = Tkinter.Entry (EasyBox1)
answr1.pack()

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox1, text="State the number of edges in a cube")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()

def next1():
    total = 0
    if not answr1.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
    elif answr1.get() == 8 :
        total = total + 1
        EasyBox1.withdraw()
        EasyBox2.deiconify()
    elif answr1.get() != 8:
            total = total
            EasyBox1.withdraw()
            EasyBox2.deiconify()
    return

#easybox2
EasyBox2 = Tkinter.Tk()
EasyBox2.geometry("250x200")
EasyBox2.title("Quesion 2")

Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="answer:").pack()

answr2 = Tkinter.Entry (EasyBox2)
answr2.pack()

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="What is the place value of the digit 4 in 76421?")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="A.Thousands B.Hundreds C.Ones D.Tens")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()

def mark():
    total = 0
    if not answr2.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
    elif answr2.get() in ["B", "b"]:
        total = total + 1
        EasyBox1.withdraw()
        ResultBox.deiconify()
    else:
        total = total
        EasyBox1.withdraw()
        ResultBox.deiconify()


EasyBox2.withdraw()

total = 0


ResultBox = Tkinter.Tk()
ResultBox.geometry("320x260")
ResultBox.title("Results")

LabelName5 = Tkinter.Label (ResultBox, text="Marks : "+`total`, font=("Impact",20))
LabelName5.grid(row=2,column=0)
ResultBox.withdraw()

Tkinter.Button (EasyBox1, text="Next", command=next1).pack()
Tkinter.Button (EasyBox2, text="result", command=mark).pack()

EasyBox1.mainloop()
```